# How can I get borderRadius to work for ToggleButtons in ToggleButtonGroup?

Tags: material-ui

I would like all of the toggle buttons to have rounded corners.

The documentation section about [ToggleButton Customization](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-toggle-button/#customization) gives an example showing altering borderLeft of middle buttons.  The easiest repro of borderRadius not working is to click the "Edit in Codesandbox" link for that source code and see that borderRadius has no effect.

Does anyone have MUI styling that can achieve this?

Thanks!

I've tried many different combinations of specificity via both sx and styled(ToggleButton/ToggleButtonGroup) but can't find anything that works.

Here's what my ToggleButton has and borderRadius does not work. Other properties work just fine. Sandbox from documentation page also proves most properties work but not borderRadius.

```
        <ToggleButton
      sx={{
        m: 0.25,
        px: 2,
        py: 0.75,
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 600,
        borderRadius: "5px",
        backgroundColor: "#F8FAFB",
        "&.Mui-selected": {
          backgroundColor: "white",
        },
      }}
      value={button}
    >
      {button}
    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: A checked the example you pointed to in Codesandbox, borderRadius works fine there.

Comment: You are correct Max.  I see it working now.  My problem was that it wasn't working in my code because I was on MUI v5.13.6 and the documentation I shared was for MUI v.5.15.4.  I looked in the previous MUI docs at v5.0.6 and it's example was different, using "&:not(:first-of-type)" which worked on my version.  Then I think my codesandbox didn't work because I didn't understand how to get it to recompile on code changes.  Ultimately, I'll try moving my code to latest version and should be fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

MaxAlex said it worked in codesandbox which led me to the answer to my problem:

My problem was that it wasn't working in my code because I was on MUI v5.13.6 and the documentation I shared was for MUI v.5.15.4. I looked in the previous MUI docs at v5.0.6 and it's example was different, using "&:not(:first-of-type)" which worked on my version. Then I think my codesandbox didn't work because I didn't understand how to get it to recompile on code changes. Ultimately, I'll try moving my code to latest version and should be fine.

Thank you Rohit Singh and MaxAlex for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying props for the button as below using `sx`

```js
const CustomToggleButton = (props) => (
  <ToggleButton
    sx={{
      borderRadius: '12px',
      '&.Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor: '#4caf50',
        color: '#fff',
      },
    }}
    {...props}
  />
);
```

then use it like this where you need the button to be displayed
`<ToggleButtonGroup {...props}>`

Comment: Thanks Rohit but that doesn't have an effect.  other props work but not borderRadius.  I put a snippet of my code in original post.  You can see it's similar to what you posted.  Can you spot any difference between yours and mine?  Thanks.

Comment: In that case you can try using the `borderRadious` property directly in the styles rather than `sx` props.
some thing like this

`<ToggleButton
  value={button}
  style={{
    m: 0.25,
    px: 2,
    py: 0.75,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 600,
    borderRadius: "5px",
    backgroundColor: "#F8FAFB",
    "&.Mui-selected": {
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
  }}
>
  {button}
</ToggleButton>`

if this also doesn't work then check for any global styles or theme settings that could be affecting the appearance of the ToggleButon